# Hide print and share button in Airprint

Tags: ios, swift

In the iOS project, we need to hide the print and share buttons from the `AirPrin`t page. How do I do this? Can anyone help?

[image: ![Airprint screen]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65jyW.png)

Comment: Of you don't want to share or print the document, what is the point of showing the dialog?

Comment: The programme operates in various states. Some states' people are unable to print, and others are unable to share due to regulatory prohibitions. Therefore, the goal of these states is to eliminate their functions. The purpose of these modifications is to guarantee adherence to state laws and regulations. If both features need to be removed, it is preferable to not display these pages; however, in these states, we only need to conceal one feature. because certain user-related data is contained in the programme.

Comment: Then I think you have no option other than to not allow printing. From the dialog you have shown the user can easily save a pdf and once they have a pdf then they can do anything they want with it.  You can't remove the share or print buttons.

Comment: That seems to be the only course of action.
thanks @Paulw11

Comment: Hi, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think we may alter anything on this page because Apple does not permit us to hide the print or share buttons.